# Target specific resolution and apply css

Tags: css

I want to target specific resolution `1600x900` and apply css only to it. I have tried this

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1899px) {
  .up { margin-top: -5%;}
}
```

And this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1900px) and (min-width: 1900px) {
  .up { margin-top: -5%;}
}
```

Both doesn't work and I don't see them in console. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: your media queries won't target 1600x900 - the top one goes from 1900xXYZ and your second one goes from 1900 - typo? change to 1600

Comment: `@media only screen and (min-width:1600px)` still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/width) to target a specific viewport width.

```
@media (width: 1600px) {
    .up { margin-top: -5%;}
}
```

Comment: Hm, this actually works. Thanks. So what exactly is difference between `min-width` and `width` in this case

Comment: @Ivan `min-width` goes from a minimum, e.g. min-width of 100 would target everything over and including the width of 100. Width is a specific, e.g. specifying width 100 means, only 100

Answer (score 1):

You are making an error, change the resolution value.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    .up {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to apply styling to the resolution above 1600px use:

```
@media screen and (width: 1600px) {
        .up {
            background-color: lightgreen;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This targets higher resolutions.

Comment: Yeah it targets any resolution higher than 1600px in width.

Comment: Even you can also use height and other conditions as well. If it worked for you accept the answer which will close the topic :)